# Appscript not firing in embeded iframe

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this appscript that is on my website.... and it is displaying all fine however it is not firing the script properly, I can see it is doing something as the file is reloading when I push the button on the website but not running the script.

```
    <iframe height="600px" width="100%" id="frame" src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/SHEET_ID/edit?usp=sharing?widget=true&amp;headers=false#=gid=0" frameborder="0" style="overflow:hidden;overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:hidden;height:100%;width:100%;position:absolute;top:70px;left:0px;right:0px;bottom:0px" ></iframe>
    

    <button onclick="savePDFs()">Save As pdf</button>
    <script>
      function savePDFs(){
        document.getElementById("frame").src = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/SHEET_ID/edit?usp=sharing?widget=true&amp;headers=false#gid=0";
      }
    </script>
```

I think it has something to do with this but I am not sure how to move forward.

```
// Serve HTML with no X-Frame-Options header (in Apps Script server-side code).
var output = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<b>Hello, world!</b>');
output.setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
```

The script I have in the google sheet....

```
function savePDFs() {
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/SHEET_ID/";
  var folders = DriveApp.getFolderById("FOLDER_ID");  // Modify

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var url_ext = 'export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf'   //export as pdf
  + '&size=letter'      // paper size
  + '&portrait=false'    // orientation, false for landscape
  + '&fitw=true'        // fit to width, false for actual size
  + '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false&pagenumbers=false'  //hide optional headers and footers
  + '&gridlines=false'  // hide gridlines
  + '&fzr=false';       // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
  var options = {headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}}
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + url_ext, options);
  var valor = sheet.getRange('A22').getValue();  // Modify
  var blob = response.getBlob().setName( valor + '.pdf');
  folders.createFile(blob);
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you clarify your goal? The button calls a function in the "outer-level" HTML called `savePDFs()` (that has the same name as the function mentioned to be defined in the Apps Script project). The way the "outer-level" `savePDFs()` is implemented it just sets a new value to the iframe `src` attribute to a Google Sheets URL. So the load behavior is due to that... If your goal was to invoke the `savePDFs()` from your Apps Script project, you won't be able to do that at the same external level as the iframe, due to understandable security reasons

Comment: Hi there, yes I was tryign to add a html button to my website that would run the script savePDFs() (the last script that I posted)

Comment: I would suggest you look at these articles [HTML Service Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices) and [google.script.run()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to execute Apps Scripts functions bound to the Sheets file you are embedded in a iframe.

Client-side API (`google.script.run`) is only available if the HTML page calling it is being served by Apps Scripts. See [this page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run) for more details.

In order to call a Apps Scripts function from outside Google Products environment, you must first deploy and prepare your project to accept external requests. For that, I recommend having a look at [Apps Scripts WebApps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web).

Deploying a Apps Scripts project as a WebApp you can serve HTML and work with  Client-side API mentioned above.